# A quick way to prove the inequality $\frac{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}{2}\le \sqrt{\frac{x+y}{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

Can anyone suggest a quick way to prove this inequality?

$$\frac{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}{2}\le \sqrt{\frac{x+y}{2}}$$

Comment: For a proof of a more general case (full QM-AM inequality), see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1249986/107671).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sides are positive so you may square the inequality ot obtain $$\begin{align*}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{2}\right)^2\le\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{2}}\right)^2 &\iff \frac{x+2\sqrt{xy}+y}{4}\le \frac{x+y}{2} \\&\iff \frac{2\sqrt{xy}}{4}\le\frac{x+y}{2}-\frac{x+y}{4} \\&\iff \sqrt{xy}\le \frac{x+y}{2}\\[0.2cm]& \iff (\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\ge 0\end{align*}$$ which is true.

Comment: The last $\iff$ seems off to me.

Comment: it was showing the pre-edit answer to me, nevermind!

Comment: @GFauxPas Due to your comment I found the mistake! You were correct, thanks for noticing!

Comment: Citing AM-GM is a bit overkill here. $\sqrt{xy}\le\frac{x+y}{2}\iff (\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\ge 0$. AM-GM refers to $\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}\le \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}$, $n\in\mathbb Z^+, x_1,\ldots,x_n >0$, which is difficult to prove.

Comment: @user31415 I agree. I always prefer to just note $a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \geq 0$ when dealing with AM-GM when $n = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

$2ab \leq a^2+b^2$ so $\frac{a+b}{2} \leq \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$. Now choose $a = \sqrt{x},b = \sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Just square the inequality $\frac{a+b}{2} \leq \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$. It is one of the most basic inequalities. All mean-type inequalities reduce to $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: @Stef: To such a question (no background, no reason, no details) I did not want to give an explicit answer. Anyone who stared more than two minutes at the inequality would square both sides, and start reducing what can be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

assuming $$x\geq0 \land y\geq0$$

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{2} \leq \sqrt{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}$$

Squaring:

$$\dfrac{x+y+2\sqrt{xy}}{4} \leq \dfrac{x+y}{2} \implies \dfrac{\sqrt{xy}}{2} \leq \dfrac{x+y}{4}$$

Squaring again

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{xy}}{2} \leq \dfrac{x+y}{4} \implies \dfrac{xy}{4} \leq \dfrac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{16}\implies$$

$$0 \leq \dfrac{x^2-2xy+y^2}{16} \implies 0 \leq \dfrac{(x-y)^2}{4}$$

But we now that $a^2\geq 0 \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ so it's true...

Comment: After squaring it's $2\sqrt{xy}$ not $\sqrt{2xy}$.

Comment: Gahh, you're right. Edited :)

Answer (score 1):

By [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), 
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum \phi(x_i) \geq \phi \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum x_i \right)$$
for $\phi(x)$ convex ($\leq$ for $\phi$ concave). In your case, $\phi(x) = \sqrt{x}$ has a negative second derivative and is hence concave, so with $n=2$ the inequality immediately holds using the concave case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of Cauchy-Schwarz ($a_i,b_i>0$):  $$\sqrt{a_1b_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{a_nb_n}\le\sqrt{(a_1+\cdots+a_n)(b_1+\cdots+b_n)}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{2}\le\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{2}}\iff\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\le\sqrt{(1+1)(x+y)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality is a special case ($n=2$) of QM-AM (quadratic-arithmetic mean) inequality:  $$\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2}{n}}\ge \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}$$

In general, $a_i>0,k_2>k_1$ gives ([Power Mean Inequality](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Power_Mean_Inequality)): $$\sqrt[k_2]{\frac{a_1^{k_2}+\cdots+a_n^{k_2}}{n}}\ge \sqrt[k_1]{\frac{a_1^{k_1}+\cdots+a_n^{k_1}}{n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Divide by $\sqrt y$ and let $t=\frac xy$ to obtain $\frac{\sqrt t+1}2\leq\sqrt\frac{t+1}2$. Comparing the derivatives of both sides, we see
$$\begin{array}{c}\left(\frac{\sqrt t+1}2\right)'&&\left(\sqrt\frac{t+1}2\right)'\\
\|&&\|\\
\frac1{2\sqrt{4t}}&\leq&\frac1{2\sqrt{2t+2}}&\quad\text{for }t\geq1\\
\frac1{2\sqrt{4t}}&\geq&\frac1{2\sqrt{2t+2}}&\quad\text{for }t\leq1\end{array}$$
so $$\frac{\sqrt t+1}2=-1+\int_1^u\left(\frac{\sqrt u+1}2\right)'du\leq-1+\int_1^u\left(\sqrt\frac{u+1}2\right)'du=\sqrt\frac{t+1}2$$
for all $t\geq0$.